# Old validation errors on clicking browser back button

Tags: javascript, asp.net, firefox

I am new and apologies if i asked age old question. I have a problem with an asp.net web application, as follows:

**Problem:**

On Page 1 i need to enter details and click next button to go to Page 2
If i had any validation error(s), i clear them and then click next button
On Page 2 if i click BROWSER BACK button, i would expect to see corrected details on page 1 but it loads the Page 1 WITH VALIDATION ERRORS.

**More information:**

The aspx of Page 1 alread has meta tags with expire set to -1 and 'no-cache' set for both cache-control and pragma properties.

On IE 8, i get 'page expired' page but on firefox 8, it automatically refreshes the page instead of showing 'page expired' page.

The issue seems to be there even on IE, when i try to refresh the page manually, i could see the old validation errors similar to FIrefox behavior.

Out of curiosity i entered improper details on page 1 in such a way i am hampered by validation errors 3 times. Then i correct details and clicked next button to reach Page 2.
On page 2 on clicking browser back button, i will get the validation errors i recieved on THIRD TIME, or the latest version of page 1 with vlidation errors.

However browser back button works fine when there were no validation errors on previous page.

Sorry for writing so much info, just thought might give you more insight into the problem.

Comment: Writing more info is almost always a good thing. Another thing that would make it easier for us to provide you with an answer would be to add (part of) the code you are using for the pages.

Comment: Try the `Wizard` control. It does what you want. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fs0za4w6.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are trying to create a wizard-like process where you take the user through multiple steps (pages) before the end goal. If that is the case, the way I've handled that in the past is through the use of Panel tags. Add a Panel tag for each step in your process and add your form elements to each. You can also have a "Next" button to progress to the next step within each Panel. When the button is clicked, hide the current Panel and unhide the next. You can also apply validation logic to the button to prevent the user from advancing with bad input. At the end, you can redirect them to a different page for a "success" message or summary. If the success page was also another Panel on the page, the user would be able to resubmit the form by refreshing the page if not handled correctly.

We've done this a lot and have never run into validation issues like the kind you are describing. I hope this helps you a little.

Comment: starting from .net 3.0 there has been a `Wizard` control. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fs0za4w6.aspx

Comment: Ah, I forgot about that thing. I've been creating my own since 2.0 and just never tried the Wizard control.

Comment: try it some time! :) It's pretty good and uses the ViewState to "remember" what you filled in the previous as well as the next screens. I almost dare to say that using the Wizard control will solve the OP's issue as well.